# Why does read-access of int*const& cause segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, segmentation-fault

Why does the below read-access of an `int*const&` result in a segmentation fault?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class X{
    int A[3][4] = {0};
public:
    int*const&p=*A;
    void print()const{
        for(int i=0;i<3;++i){
            for(int j=0;j<4;++j){
                std::cout << A[i][j] << " , ";
            }
            std::cout << "\n";
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    X x;
    x.p[2] = 3;
    x.print(); // until this point, everything works as intended

    std::cout << x.p[2] << "\n"; // why does read-access of p trigger segmentation fault?
}
```

Output

```
0 , 0 , 3 , 0 , 
0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 
0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 
Segmentation fault
```

### Application Context

I want an n-D array `A` for internal computations with easier indexing in a dynamic programming context, but the external interface requests a pointer `p` to a 1D array.

### Potential Explanation

The above code works when replacing `int*const& p=*A;` with `int*const p=*A;`. Is the real issue in the fact that the internal int array of A[][] is inaccessible for assignment?

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings. My compiler tells me twice that what happens here is wrong: https://godbolt.org/z/noffGbdc4. Undefined Behaviour can do anything, including "crashing in a seemingly unrelated place".

Comment: Why would you even want to use ` int*const&p` ? Ever thought about returning a const reference to a `std::array<std::array<int,4>,3>` (through a getter function, instead of a public member).

Comment: @Yksisarvinen So you say line 6 is the incorrect command for acquiring a pointer member that points at A[0][0] ? Is there then a way to construct such a member at all?

Comment: Don't write code like that. It's blatant obfuscation and just doesn't add or do anything useful. Be precise, be explicit, and write good, clean and ***maintainable*** code.

Comment: @PepijnKramer: Because the code where X is used in requests a pointer p and shall not be changed. (workplace. I never ask/challenge given specifications.)

Comment: It's wrong not to challenge specifications, that's the first thing you should do with any single specification. "Why?" is *the* question to ask on everything any engineer ever makes. And especially in software engineering, where [XY problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) are most common.

Comment: @violetvanillavendetta I think challenging bad decissions is always a good idea. I agree with Some programmer dude, this code is just wrong. And you have a very good argument, this code crashes (because it is too easy to use wrong) which is never a good idea for a product. Show your collegues my example and let them read the  [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines)

Comment: Also : If the code that uses X's data needs a pointer you can still use [std::array's data()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/data) method

Comment: You expose a reference to a pointer, but you have no pointer that lives long enough. The only pointer you have is a temporary which dies immediately after initialising the reference. The reference thus becomes dangling.

Comment: You cannot use 1D access of an entire 2D array.  That's UB.  You can use 1D access of a **row** of the 2D array; but not by using `int*const&p=*A;`.  If your compiler did not warn you of the problem, check to see if you have warnings enabled.  You'd be better off with a public member function that maps the 1D index into the 2D array and returns the element (or reference to the element).  Arrays are **not pointers**.  Due to *pointer decay*, they implicitly convert to a pointer to the first element at the drop of a hat.

Answer (score 0):

In current C++ you would use std::array and references to that array (just like any other C++ object, you can return std::array from a function).
You should not have public data, always provide getters (easier to refactor certainly with the auto keyword).

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

class X
{
public:

    //read only (used when there is a "const X" or "const X&" being used
    //like in stream operator below
    // No need type std::array<std::array<int, 4>, 3> over and over again, just use auto
    const auto& get_values() const noexcept
    {
        return m_values;
    }

    // read/write for non-const situations.
    auto& get_values() noexcept
    {
        return m_values;
    }

private:
    // nice thing about std::array is you can return
    // it from functions by (const) reference (like get_values)
    std::array<std::array<int, 4>, 3> m_values{};
};


// replacement of your print, generic output to a stream
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const X& x)
{
    auto& values = x.get_values();

    // whenever you can use range based for loops
    for (const auto& row : values)
    {
        bool comma{ false };
        for (const auto& value : row)
        {
            if (comma) os << ", ";
            os << value;
            comma = true;
        }
        os << "\n";
    }

    return os;
}
    

int main() 
{
    X x;

    // get a reference to the 2D array
    auto& values = x.get_values();

    // then assign a value into this array
    // this is also where one of your mistakes was, assinging an int to a whole row
    values[2][2] = 3;
 
    std::cout << x; // use stream operator for X

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I respect all your advice. The issue is twofold: I am given a task where I have to rectify a code without changing its external interface. Also, it is for embedded targets, where containers do not exist. And all that is a subject of workplace. I don't question this because my own projects I do indeed in the ways that I deem good practice and where I agree with all the comments. It just does not help me at earning my supper. And if the proposal is then to find a different workplace then again I respect that, but it does not help me short-term :)

Comment: std::array does not have dynamic memory allocation and should be completely safe for embedded as well.  And no I am not saying you should change workplace, income is somewhat important ;)   I just hope the workplace can learn from you too, C++ has a lot to offer even for embedded (templates, compile time constexpr etc.). Good luck